# How can I add a generated column in MySQL/MariaDB that will caculate a date from information in other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, calculated-columns, date-arithmetic

I understand how to add a generated column using MariaDB (supports the same syntax as MySQL) and have done so with this table using a simple arithmetic operation.  However when I try to use the DATE_SUB function I get the syntax error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=28594) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WEEKS)) STORED' at line 3
```

The code I am using is:

```
ALTER TABLE `ExampleTable`
ADD COLUMN `DOB` DATE
AS (DATE_SUB (`DateExpected`, INTERVAL `Age` WEEKS)) STORED;
```

I would like to calculate DOB from DateExpected and Age values.

From the CREATE TABLE:

```
  `DateExpected` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Substituting with:

```
AS (DATE_SUB('1998-01-02', INTERVAL 31 DAY) STORED;
```

gives a similar error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=28594) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'STORED' at line 3
```

But substituting with:

```
AS (`DateExpected`) STORED;
```

works just fine at populating the DOB column with values from DateExpected, so I suppose this has to do with the DATE_SUB statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ALTER TABLE `ExampleTable`
    ADD COLUMN `DOB` DATE
    AS (`DateExpected` - INTERVAL `Age` WEEK) STORED;
```